# Traversing a 2D or 3D array/matrix on its boundary only

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, matrix, traversal

I know how to traverse every element of a 2D array, using `array[i % n, i / n]` when i=0 < n*m for a n,m array. Is there a handy formula to traverse the boundary elements of a 2D array only?

for example, for 2D, given a matrix

[image]

only 'a' is traversed. Wish i could illustrate for 3d but hope this clears it up

Comment: Does traversal order matter?

Comment: Why you prefer this method over nested loops?

Comment: traversal order does not matter

Comment: For a 3D, by boundary do you mean edges or faces?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I had misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Is it a square matrix (nxn) or rectangular (mxn)?

Comment: for 3D i mean edges only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with for 2D: (it's Java, but to convert to C#, you should only have to replace `System.out.print` and `Math.ceil` with the C# equivalents)

```
int n = 5, m = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < 2*(m+n); i++)
{
   int x1 = i/(m+2*n),
       x2 = (i%(m+n))%n,
       x3 = (int)Math.ceil(((m+i)%(m+n)) / m / (1.0*n));

   System.out.print(x1*(n-1) + x2 * x3 + " ");

   int y1 = i/(m+n) - i/(m+2*n),
       y2 = x2,
       y3 = (int)Math.ceil((i%(m+n)) / n / (1.0*m));

   System.out.println(y1*(m-1) + y2 * y3);
}
```

The above can of course be written as a single statement that accesses the array if you wish.

Note that, because of `(i%(m+n))%n`, this only works if `n > m`. The simplest work-around for this is probably to stick this into a function that takes 4 parameters `x,y,m,n`, which can easily be swapped depending on whether `m` or `n` is larger.

Output:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 2
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
4 0
4 1
4 2
```

[**Live demo**](https://ideone.com/wUbJps).

As you can see, it does repeat 4 corner cells, if that's okay.

Let's see what each `xi` looks like (without the `Math.ceil` and `/(1.0*m)` or `/(1.0*n)`):

```
 i   x1 x2 x3   y1 y2 y3
 0    0  0  1    0  0  0
 1    0  1  1    0  1  0
 2    0  2  1    0  2  0
 3    0  3  2    0  3  0
 4    0  4  2    0  4  0
 5    0  0  0    0  0  1
 6    0  1  0    0  1  1
 7    0  2  0    0  2  1
 8    0  0  1    1  0  0
 9    0  1  1    1  1  0
10    0  2  1    1  2  0
11    0  3  2    1  3  0
12    0  4  2    1  4  0
13    1  0  0    0  0  1
14    1  1  0    0  1  1
15    1  2  0    0  2  1
```

The `Math.ceil` and `/(1.0*m)` or `/(1.0*n)` is just there to change `x3` and `y3` to 1 where they're > 1 (which will happen if the applicable limit (`m` or `n`) is greater than the other limit (`n` or `m`).

The above table can then be used to get the desired traversal by multiplying the first with `the limit-1` and adding the product of the second and the third, as can be seen in the `print` statements in the code.

Figuring out that the above table would be useful, how to generate it and how to use it was just a matter of playing around a bit.

Yeah, I'm not figuring that out for 3D.

As you can see, something slightly longer is way more readable:

```
int n = 5, m = 3;
int x = 0, y = 0;
int xInc = 1, yInc = 0;
while (true)
{
   System.out.println(x + " " + y);
   // got to right, go down
   if (x == n-1 && xInc == 1)
   {
      xInc = 0;
      yInc = 1;
   }
   // got to bottom, go left
   else if (y == m-1 && yInc == 1)
   {
      xInc = -1;
      yInc = 0;
   }
   // got to left, go up
   else if (x == 0 && xInc == -1)
   {
      xInc = 0;
      yInc = -1;
   }
   // got to top, stop
   else if (y == 0 && yInc == -1)
   {
      break;
   }
   x += xInc;
   y += yInc;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
4 1
4 2
3 2
2 2
1 2
0 2
0 1
0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming clockwise or anticlockwise traversal, Maybe something like, for 1st index:

```
for n = 5, m = 3.
 0 1 2 3 4
11       5
10 9 8 7 6

For i = 0 to 2m + 2n - 5
[ max( i - max( i - (n-1), 0) - max( i - (m+n-2), 0 ), 0) ]

column index first increase from 0 to n-1
Then it stays constant at n-1 upto i = n+m-2
Then it decreases along with i to 0 upto i = 2n + m - 3
Then again it stays constant at 0 upto 2n + 2m - 5.
```

The graph is:

```
  n-1_________
    /         \
   /           \
  /             \__________
 0   n-1   n+m-2 2n+m-3  2n+2m-5
```

For second index:
The graph is:

```
        _______
       /       \
      /         \
 ____/           \
 0   n n+m  2n+m 2n+2m
```

You can form similar expression using i.

Comment: please elaborate on this. I dont understand the graph you've used. Plus for a zero based array, this may overrun the index

Comment: @TheJackal I have added clarification in my answer. Please check.